# will Unity ads work while i put no physical address in my Unity profile nor my Google play developers console?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, ads, unityads

I created a simple 2D android game and made it generate ads using UnityAds, I have no physical address inserted in the google play developers profile (since my game is free and contains no in-app purchases) so will this affect the revenues from this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get paid from google is it not necessary to put your adress there.
It will not affect the revenues from other services.